# How to figure out correct interfaces for a component in UML component diagrams?

Tags: interface, components, uml, component-diagram

I have a doubt about UML component diagrams interfaces. I have a search component in my system which is responsible for search some product from the database and return the search result to the user. I have drawn search component in 3 different ways as I understood. I want to know which way is the correct one and best in practice and why others are not correct.

[image]

In this case I thought search component provides a `Search interface` to other components like `User` and they use that `Search interface` to search. Also the user passes search parameters through that `interface` and get the result through that `interface` as well.

[image]

In this case I thought Search component provides `Search interface` and and `User` uses that `interface` to pass search params. And it fetch data from the database. Then `User` component uses `Search result interface` to get the search result.

[image]

In this scenario, I thought `Search component` need search params to search something. So, It requires Search params. Therefore, I added `Search params required interface`. After fetching data Search component provides that result. So, I've added `provide interface` named `search result`.

These are the ways I thought about this Search Component. I don't have a Idea which one is the correct one. Please explain which one is the correct one and why others are not correct.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lollipops and sockets do not tell what goes in and out but who provides or needs the interface definitions. So, simply spoken, the first variant would be correct. The `Search` interface offers some `search(...)` operations which yield some result. And the data must be provided via the `Data` interface. The component's task would then be to implement a search on data according to these interfaces.

It would help you if you would place the «interfaces» near the socket/lollipop and draw dependency/realization accordingly. For example like this:

[image]

Comment: Because of lollipop & socket do not tell what goes in and out, Can we user `persistence interface` of the `Persistence component` to get data from the database to other components? (Can other components get the data from the database through the persistence interface)  https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ejSL.png

Comment: @Kasun Sure. The left dependencies should point the other way round, though. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23456112/what-is-the-difference-between-required-and-provided-interfaces